# SQL/PySpark: Create a new column consisting of a number of rows in the past n days

Tags: sql, pyspark

Currently, I have a table consisting of `encounter_id` and `date` field like so:

```
+---------------------------+--------------------------+
|encounter_id               |date                      |
+---------------------------+--------------------------+
|random_id34234             |2018-09-17 21:53:08.999999|
|this_can_be_anything2432432|2018-09-18 18:37:57.000000|
|423432                     |2018-09-11 21:00:36.000000|
+---------------------------+--------------------------+
```

`encounter_id` is a random string.

I'm aiming to create a column which consists of the total number of encounters in the past 30 days.

```
+---------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+
|encounter_id               |date                      | encounters_in_past_30_days|
+---------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+
|random_id34234             |2018-09-17 21:53:08.999999| 2                         |
|this_can_be_anything2432432|2018-09-18 18:37:57.000000| 3                         |
|423432                     |2018-09-11 21:00:36.000000| 1                         |
+---------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Currently, I'm thinking of somehow using window functions and specifying an aggregate function.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: could you please add your expected output?

Comment: Sure. the expected output is a column **total_encounters_in_the_past_30_days** where the first entry will be 2 (occurrences of the last entry and the first entry), the second entry will be 3 (occurrences of all the entries), and the third entry will only be 1 (itself).

Comment: Your Question is so unclear, that it will be difficult to do anything. What should be the basis for aggregation, in other words `groupby` what? How did you get `2/3/1` for `encounters_in_past_30_days`? How is first entry 2? They have different `date` and `encounter_id`. What's the basis of grouping? It's an open ended Question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution, I added some sample data. It indeed uses a window function, as you suggested yourself. Hope this helps!

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [
     ('A','2018-10-01 00:15:00'),
     ('B','2018-10-11 00:30:00'),
     ('C','2018-10-21 00:45:00'),
     ('D','2018-11-10 00:00:00'),
     ('E','2018-12-20 00:15:00'),
     ('F','2018-12-30 00:30:00')
    ],
    ("encounter_id","date")
)

df = df.withColumn('timestamp',F.col('date').astype('Timestamp').cast("long"))
w = Window.orderBy('timestamp').rangeBetween(-60*60*24*30,0)
df = df.withColumn('encounters_past_30_days',F.count('encounter_id').over(w))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+------------+-------------------+----------+-----------------------+
|encounter_id|               date| timestamp|encounters_past_30_days|
+------------+-------------------+----------+-----------------------+
|           A|2018-10-01 00:15:00|1538345700|                      1|
|           B|2018-10-11 00:30:00|1539210600|                      2|
|           C|2018-10-21 00:45:00|1540075500|                      3|
|           D|2018-11-10 00:00:00|1541804400|                      2|
|           E|2018-12-20 00:15:00|1545261300|                      1|
|           F|2018-12-30 00:30:00|1546126200|                      2|
+------------+-------------------+----------+-----------------------+
```

---

> EDIT: If you want to have days as the granularity, you could first convert your date column to the `Date` type. Example below, assuming that a window of five days means today and the four days before. If it should be today and the past five days just remove the `-1`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

n_days = 5

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [
     ('A','2018-10-01 23:15:00'),
     ('B','2018-10-02 00:30:00'),
     ('C','2018-10-05 05:45:00'),
     ('D','2018-10-06 00:15:00'),
     ('E','2018-10-07 00:15:00'),
     ('F','2018-10-10 21:30:00')
    ],
    ("encounter_id","date")
)

df = df.withColumn('timestamp',F.to_date(F.col('date')).astype('Timestamp').cast("long"))
w = Window.orderBy('timestamp').rangeBetween(-60*60*24*(n_days-1),0)
df = df.withColumn('encounters_past_n_days',F.count('encounter_id').over(w))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------------+
|encounter_id|               date| timestamp|encounters_past_n_days|
+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------------+
|           A|2018-10-01 23:15:00|1538344800|                     1|
|           B|2018-10-02 00:30:00|1538431200|                     2|
|           C|2018-10-05 05:45:00|1538690400|                     3|
|           D|2018-10-06 00:15:00|1538776800|                     3|
|           E|2018-10-07 00:15:00|1538863200|                     3|
|           F|2018-10-10 21:30:00|1539122400|                     3|
+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you! How should I go about this if the granularity of each day is by date, instead of by 24 hour difference?

Comment: @VVNoodle updated my answer, hope this is what you were looking for!